# qdap, rJava load failed

Tags: r

I have successfully installed all the libraries but below error is not going away

1. I have tried 3 JDK java-se-8u41-ri ; openjdk11 ; openjdk8 and below error keeps coming, when I open in R-Studio it works but not whe i try to make exe using electron, please advise
   stderr:Error: package or namespace load failed for 'qdap':
   .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
   call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
   error: unable to load shared object 'C:/Users//R-Portable-Win/library/rJava/libs/x64/rJava.dll':
   LoadLibrary failure:  %1 is not a valid Win32 application.